# Windows 7 asking for password when connecting to WIndows 2000 server

Tags: remote-access, windows-server-2000

I have gone through all topics specified on Superuser. But none of the information I've found works for me.

My problem is when connecting to a Windows 2000 Server, a security window appears asking for a network password. The funny this is that I didn't configure such a password.

The client I am trying to connect to the server from is a Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit laptop.

Comment: we try to help each other here in the community so that others might also benefit from it , try not to share your email id that's not how this forum operates

Comment: does your Windows server have a password ? if not set one and then try using it

Answer (score 0):

How do you try to connect? As far as I know there have to be group permissions including your use or an anyone user to access the server without using a password. If you use Remote-Desktop, you will always need a password, if you don't set a passwd in this case, you won't be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If are attempting to connect via Remote Desktop, you will need a password. Blank passwords are not allowed. Set a password on your Windows 2000 Server and then attempt to connect, it will go through as expected.